# How to generate province polygons in topojson

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I'm trying to build a map of the provinces of South Africa using D3.js and TopoJSON. I have tried creating GeoJSON output using the GRASS plugins to QGIS and that seems to work - I can see the individual polygons in the GeoJSON output, with appropriate IDs etc.

I have converted the GeoJSON file to a TopoJSON file and I can see the (single) outline of South Africa in my finl HTML page, however I can't seem to produce multiple polygons in the TopoJSON file for the provinces (akin to US States).

Do I need to use any specific parameter to force the generation of the province polygons. My SVG has just a single path.

Comment: Okay, as usual I bashed my head agaist a wall for several hours, posted a question and then <blam!> fixed my original problem. Next issue is how to add class attribute to enable css formatting ... hopefully the act of posting with trigger another inspiration, but if anyone else can help in the meantime ...?

Comment: As predicted ... fixed it. If anyone comes this way I have experience, if not knowledge of building my own map from scrath using QGIS and TopoJSON. Thanks Mike!

Comment: Glad to hear you answered your own questions. You might consider closing this question, or posting your own answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great geoJSON dataset of South African provinces:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MeganBeckett/9101ba77bd0af06fd003ea5c99d051ab/raw/eca3b12ed76be816c4dce2c0954752b63bd3f804/sa-provinces.json

Load this file as follows:

```
Promise.all([
d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MeganBeckett/9101ba77bd0af06fd003ea5c99d051ab/raw/eca3b12ed76be816c4dce2c0954752b63bd3f804/sa-provinces.json"),
    ]).then(function ([provinces]) {
      console.log(provinces)
});
```

Results:

```
{type: 'FeatureCollection', name: 'sa-provinces', crs: {…}, features: Array(9)}
crs
: 
{type: 'name', properties: {…}}
features
: 
Array(9)
0
: 
{type: 'Feature', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}, id: 'Northern Cape'}
1
: 
{type: 'Feature', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}, id: 'KwaZulu-Natal'}
2
: 
{type: 'Feature', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}, id: 'Free State'}
3
: 
{type: 'Feature', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}, id: 'Eastern Cape'}
4
: 
{type: 'Feature', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}, id: 'Limpopo'}
5
: 
{type: 'Feature', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}, id: 'North West'}
6
: 
{type: 'Feature', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}, id: 'Mpumalanga'}
7
: 
{type: 'Feature', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}, id: 'Western Cape'}
8
: 
{type: 'Feature', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}, id: 'Gauteng'}
length
: 
9
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
name
: 
"sa-provinces"
type
: 
"FeatureCollection"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

Credit: MeganBeckett (https://twitter.com/meganrogers_za/status/1186585817197830145)